# MySQL min/max with joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a search query that is successfully grabbing all the results I need. I also am checking for a count of all rows (beyond the last queries limit), a count on distinct category id's and now I just need a min/max, hopefully in the same query.

The problem I see is that its from a joined query, so I would need to join, match every connected id, then check the number I want to min/max.

So say I have 20 results, all with different "prices" but the prices are in another table and i want to find the lowest and highest price from that other table. I only need one result for the min and max, so I might as well add it with my count query (because it must also bypass the limit portion of the main query).

Any thoughts on this?

Here is some extra details (the main queries join)

```
$query->join('LEFT','#__mrsp AS m
   ON (t.name = m.name AND m.mrsp = 
     (SELECT min(mrsp) FROM #__mrsp WHERE name = t.name))');
```

`name` in this case is a unique numerical value, so it works like id. This is also `joomla` database syntax.

I am selecting the minimum in this join as there can be multiple results for one mrsp (multiple suppliers) so I only need the lowest one for the main query. To extend my question slightly the "max" needs to be the highest returned "min" value, but that is less important.

EDIT:

Here is a little more details.

Basically each product has lets say has 50 suppliers, I want the min price of them all to bring it down to 1.

Now if there is 1300 products after the min join there should be 1300 prices attached as well, so i would want 1 column for the min found price and one for the highest found price.

This will lead to a result showing the lowest price that any result will have, and the highest price and result will have during your search.

So to say if there is 50 suppliers for each product the table for prices would have 50*1300 rows. I need 1300 - 1300 rows so that initial min is perfect for that.

Here is a build of the current query:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(m.mrsp) max_price,
  MIN(m.mrsp) min_price 
FROM #__products t 
LEFT JOIN #__mrsp m ON t.name = m.name 
WHERE IF(t.width IS NOT NULL, IF(t.w_override, t.j_width, t.width), t.j_width) = 17 
  AND (t.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR t.publish_up <= '2013-07-25 20:14:22') 
  AND (t.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR t.publish_down >= '2013-07-25 20:14:22')       
  AND t.state = 1 
ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: And what is the problem  now ??

Comment: Its returning the min as the max and the max as the min, or just returning the wrong value. Currently trying to look into it.

Comment: You query has to many ifs. Try first you query only with the join and order by. Look if it giving you the right results. Then you continue to add the condition one by one and test it each time what results it brings you.

Comment: I think I found it out, was nothing wrong with the query but in the data. I did not think to verify it was looking for a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should order by product id and select MAX(price), MIN(Price). Maybe you have to do two separate queries if it doesn't allow you to select the min and max in the same SQL statement.

For ex.

```
Select name, Max(price, Min(price) from products join 
customer on customer_fk = customer_id
order by product_id(or in your case product_name)
```

Comment: The min/max would be based on all products, not just the matches on mrsp. So if there are 1300 results, I would need to find the highest price and lowest price based on all 1300 results.

Comment: You want to find the highest price comparing each product with it self or you want to find the highest price of all products ?

Comment: I updated question to go into a little more detail on that, its always hard to explain the question until you see what people get confused on. Sorry about any confusion.

Comment: Chekc my new edited answer. I hope it helps you man. In case it helps you please give me an up ;)

Comment: Getting me confused results but a start, i will up-vote. Right now its grabbing the lowest as the highest and the highest as the lowest.

Comment: Can i see your query ?

Comment: I may have found the reason, if that's not it I will add it to the question.

Comment: OK. Then i will see if i can help you